# Как сделать Axios запрос по ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, reactjs

я делаю MERN приложение доставки еды. В бек-ендовой части совсем новичок. Получилось запустить сервер з базою данных MongoDB, через хуки useState i useEffect + Axios я принял все данные:

```
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('api/products')
         .then(res => {
             console.log(res)
             setProducts(res.data)
         })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
})
```

Но проблема в том, что я не могу добавить item-ы в корзину, не пойму почему старый код не работает(работал когда стейт у меня был на фронте). Мне нужно делать отдельный запрос через Axios по id или это можно как то обойти?? Подскажите пожалуйста)))

```
    let [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([])


const addProduct = (product) => {
    const productExist = cartItems.find(item => item.id === product.id)
    if (productExist) {
        setCartItems(cartItems.map(item => item.id === product.id?
            {...productExist, quantity: productExist.quantity + 1}: item));
    } else {
        setCartItems([...cartItems, {...product, quantity: 1}])
    }
```

Comment: На [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com) вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Stanislav, you bothered to make a translation, but you didn't understand that the stackoverflow website is a russian version, so?

Comment: @Stanislav, если вы используете русскую версию сайта, побудьте добры писать на русском, иначе я не уверен, что я смогу разговаривать с данными получаемыми из датабазы (`I'm get all data from database`)...